# Printing the image on lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, lightbox

I've done so much search but can't find any working solution to my problem. I've got a lightbox on my page, when I put a 'print' button and on lightbox layer click it, it prints the whole page but I'd like it to print only the image opened via lightbox. Is this possible? I think I need a bit of JS but really don't know how to do, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful http://sandbox.tse-webdesign.be/lightbox-print/ 
or answer to this question [Making a lightbox support printing on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801259/making-a-lightbox-support-printing-on-web-page)